# firebase-admin-python is slow when calling get_user with multiple requests

Tags: django, firebase, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

From an endpoint, we are retrieving the user data from firebase using the get_user method from the firebase-admin-python library. The problem is that, when calling the endpoint with high load, the requests to firebase degrade the endpoint's response time.

The application is built on top of Django Rest Framework and deployed on gcloud Kubernetes cluster. We are using gunicorn, eventlet workers.